# Street View preload

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth-plugin, google-street-view

We experience a problem with Google Street View. We want to move there using API. So, let's say, initially we load certain panoramic view. Then, we move forward for a few meters and want to load everything again with the new coordinates. What we observe is that several images are loading very slow and the result is a piece-meal panorama - with some images new, some old and some in process of being loaded.

Is there any way to optimize that process? For example, can we pre-load images in Street View? Or, can we implement the same technique that Google Street View app is using - when the entire panorama is blurred while we are moving and then loads everything together?

This is function we use:

```
panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
    panorama.setPov({
    heading: me.heading,
    zoom:1,
    pitch:0
});
```

Comment: It seems that the answer is NO - there is no way to improve performance there by programmatic means. According to our own research and communication with Google Earth support, we have no control over the load. The reason we get blurred images in the Google Street View application - and subsequently much better performance - is that they reduce resolution during the move. We have no access to that functionality and cannot see how they do it - because it is obfuscated by HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.

If you have defined motions, you can set map-canvas to `display:none`, execute your animation and reset your variables, then you set to `display:block` back and execute your animations again.

There are a issues and requests to Google Maps API, let's request this feature there!

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list